# how to fix error in conditional date subtraction in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Date substraction.

hello everyone, can anyone help me to get previous day date from the selected date. Including this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(B2)=5,"0"&B2,B2)
```

[image]

I am getting date in cell B2 like 041022 and I want 031022 in cell A2.

Comment: These are not date values. This explains how dates work in Excel https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***may try*** using this formula, assumption is you are taking years after `2000`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=TEXT(TEXT(REPLACE(IF(LEN(B2)=5,0&B2,B2),5,0,20),"00\/00\/0000"),"dd-mm-yyyy")-1
```

---

Or, one can use a **[LET()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)** function if they are using either **Excel 2021 or MS365**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A9`

```
=LET(_number,IF(LEN(B9)=5,0&B9,B9),
DATE(RIGHT(_number,2),MID(_number,3,2),LEFT(_number,2))-1)
```

---

Here is another alternative, if one have access to `TEXTJOIN()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A19`

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,MID(IF(LEN(B19)=5,0&B19,B19),{3,1,5},{2,2,2}))-1
```

---

**Note:** Since dates are stored as numbers in Excel, hence it will return as numbers, need to format as Excel Dates by either pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> from **Format Cells** dialog click **Number** Tab and select **Date** press **Ok**.

---